# AjaxHelper MVC6 vnext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, ajaxhelper

i don't find the Ajax helper into asp.net vnext mvc 6. 
is it delete from project  or replace by view component ?

I search in the github repository and i don't see the file.
may be to install an nuget package.

I found the nuget package "Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax": "3.2.3-beta1", only require the jquery version 1.8.

Comment: so, what's your issue? be more clear

Comment: Is that the AjaxHelper has been removed in mvc 6 ? In this case what she has been replaced ?

Answer (score 4):

This request is tracked by the following item: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2015

AjaxHelpers are not being tracked for MVC 6.0 at the moment. We are planning to make unobtrusive ajax available on Bower.

We are debating how much of the AjaxHelpers if any we are going to bring back. But either way we will provide samples at some point showing exactly how to achieve the sample functionality.

Comment: Ok thanks. It's me that i posted the issue on aspnet repository.

Comment: Thanks for opening the issue. Can you please add to the issue what specific APIs you are using from the Ajax helper.

Our current plan is to make the javascript available on bower. https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2021 and some of the items are as simple as adding an attribute on the tag. So if you can provide more information, I might be able to provide more specific feedback.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive

you can use the attribute to call server by ajax request